# Get site title by its URL using REST

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, rest

I am trying to get a User Profile property that contains an URL for a SharePoint site,
then I want to use this URL to get the site title using REST API.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below query to get the user profile property of current user

```
http://siteurl/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetMyProperties?$select=PropertyName
```

The next part is a bit tricky because of CROSS-DOMAIN issues. To read the sitetile of current web use below query

```
https://yoursite.sharepoint/_api/web/title
```

You can follow below link for cross domain web title

http://sundarnarasiman.net/?p=536

Comment: obviously it's working for SP2013 sites but not for SP2010, is there a way to make it work on Sharepoint 2010 site?

Comment: You should use Webservice in that case. You can use ajax and query. Or ClientObject model.

Comment: Intresting, can you recommend me a tutorial or an article about this solution?

Comment: [Webservice](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee705814(v=office.14).aspx) [ClientObjectModel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee537247(v=office.14).aspx)