# SharePoint Designer Workflow for writing Site name to a list Column

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, workflow

I have a site structure to organize project sites on SharePoint Online.

```
Site Collection = Business unit (Eg. "Europe")
      -- Site = Country (Eg. "Norway")
          -- Subsite = Project name
```

On the project subsite I have document libraries. The documents and document sets should be tagged with all of the above in separate columns. (Eg. `Europe` + `Norway`+ `Project site name`)

Any advice on how to accomplish this with a SharePoint Designer Workflow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I'm sorry for not being able to provide screenshots to you.

For resolving your problem I'm thinking about the SP API. You can find an exemple of using the API with a workflow on [this blog post](https://sergeluca.wordpress.com/2013/04/09/calling-the-sharepoint-2013-rest-api-from-a-sharepoint-designer-workflow/), I tried it for a project and it works very well. So, here is a method, step-by-step :

1. Get the current site URL (project level) using workflow context variables
2. Build the API URL with "**site_url** */_api/web/title*" (see [this post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/120146/get-site-title-by-its-url-using-rest))
3. Add an HTTP Request in your workflow (see first link)
4. Extract the title from the JSON response variable (again, see first link)
5. Set your column with the result
6. *Repeat with BU and Country level by spliting the URL on the "/".*

If your site tree structure is "static", you could also use a list for referencing the project-to-country relation and call this with the API (one call vs. three).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thx! I'll try this approach :)