# how to populate a list column with the Site Title

Tags: sharepoint-online, designer-workflow, custom-list, site-column, auto-populate

So I have a list in a site template that needs to contain certain information about the site automatically. I need a way to fill the Title column of the list with the Site Title and the Project Owner column with column with the content of the Owners permission group.

Is there a way to either auto populate these fields on site creation or perform this action with a workflow?

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this using workflow. To populate a list column with the Site Tile, you need to use the API. You could read this for more:[SharePoint Designer Workflow for writing Site name to a list Column](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/167560/sharepoint-designer-workflow-for-writing-site-name-to-a-list-column)

To fill the Project Owner column  with the content of the Owners permission group, just use the set filed in current item like this:

[image]